# Add a custom field to jira (create issue) with a plugin

Tags: plugins, jira

I'm wondering if theres a possibility to add a Custom Field (A Textfield for ex.) to the Create Issue Screen (Default Screen). I already managed this by using the Web-GUI, but now i want to do this with a plugin.

Comment: Fields in JIRA are added to create, edit or view screens. The screens are defined for each issue type using a screen scheme, then an issue type screen scheme. A plugin would allow you to define a new custom field *type*, which you would then use to add a new custom field of that type to JIRA.

Comment: I checked your profile and can't decide if you're a bot or not!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your Reply. I already added a new custom field type by using a plugin, but actually don't need a new _type_ - i just want to add a checkbox or a plain textfield to the create issue screen. I searched the whole atlassian-docs, but all the examples are using the webgui :/ Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to add existing custom field to existing screen from your plugin code:

```
FieldScreenManager fieldScreenManager = ComponentAccessor.getFieldScreenManager();
FieldScreen screen = fieldScreenManager.getFieldScreen(screenID);
FieldScreenTab defaultTab = screen.getTab(0);
defaultTab.addFieldScreenLayoutItem(customFieldID);
```

Check [FieldScreenManager](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/screen/FieldScreenManager.html) and [FieldScreen](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/screen/FieldScreen.html) javadocs for detailed info.